# Excel Vlookup lookup_value usage

Tags: excel

What is difference using lookup_value as value and as range

```
=VLOOKUP($A2;'new prices'!$A$2:$B$15;2;FALSE) ' in each cell A2:A5
=VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$5;'new prices'!$A$2:$B$15;2;FALSE) ' or  in each cell A2:A5
```

Result seems the same, so why some people using Ranges in lookup_value, where is difference?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference except that the $A$2:$A$5 form means you cannot copy the formulas to elsewhere, but is very slightly faster. I would recommended keeping the first form.